# Disk usage increasing on its own

Tags: ubuntu, disk-space, df

I am using ubuntu 13.10. I checked disk usage using `df`. Following was the result

`df --block-size=1 /dev/sda1
Filesystem        1B-blocks       Used   Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1      103327698944 8313483264 89741791232   9% /`

I checked the same again after 10-15 minutes, and I got this
`df --block-size=1 /dev/sda1
Filesystem        1B-blocks       Used   Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1      103327698944 8419606528 89635667968   9% /`

How come the used space increased by around 100 MB when I was not downloading anything ?

Answer (score 2):

Try looking at the files that have changed in the last 15 minutes with:

```
find / -xdev -mmin -15
```

Downloading files is hardly the only thing that can consume disk space... (Misconfigured) logging, events that keep spamming logfiles which may signify another problem that needs to be dealt with, automated updates, etc. are common culprits.

Comment: as far as i know updates in ubuntu require root authorisation, how could that be a reason ? am i wrong on this ?

Comment: Updated packages may be downloaded in the background, only the installation could require authorisation but don't get stuck on it, since it's only one of the possibilities. Have you actually checked the result of this command?

Comment: i did but i was not able to scroll up in terminal since results were a lot. now i know how to handle this.could you please tell me how to see files which were modified or created from a date:time to another date:time?

Comment: I hate to be the RTFM guy but if you checked what the command I gave you did, you'd probably have found out how to change it to do just what you wanted. `man find`